# JS loaders with minimal code footprint

Tags: javascript, loader, amd

A few days ago I ran into problem that meant I needed JS loader.

I have the following files:

```
#c.js
var c = {//something};

#b.js
var b = Object.create(c);

#main.js
var a = Object.create(b);
a.foo = 'bar';
```

I need to load this files sequentially, starting from "c.js".

I did some quick research on js loaders and found out that many of them don't work (or do work but in ugly manner) with deep dependencies like my example, and just launch a callback function as soon as they will get loaded given dependency, without worrying about dependencies in given dependency(if you now what i mean).

Althought some serious loaders like requireJs can do that, but I find them a bit annoying b/c of such cases:

```
define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'views/projects/list',
  'views/users/list'
], function($, _, Backbone, Session, projectListView, userListView){
```

...too much of code, for just few dependencies.

Also I don't like that I should modify some script, so they would return something like for jQuery, when it should return $.

Too save my time and avoid trying all of loaders, I created this question.

**So, the big question is, which JS loader could do the following:**

1. Load "deep" dependencies, like my example, when callback() will be launched only when all dependencies and all dependencies of dependencies(...and so on is) loaded.
2. Have small footprint, just like having one reuqire function, with dependencyList and callback, and without need for having "callback" to return and being passed something(because usually I have my own namespace, like g.a, g.b, g.c).

Some example how I would like to see it:

```
#c.js
require([], function(){
var c = {//something};
});

#b.js
require(['c.js'], function(){
var b = Object.create(c);
});

#main.js
require(['b.js'], function(){
var a = Object.create(b);
a.foo = 'bar';
});
```

*sorry for my english.

P.s. - actually I wrote my own loader, which does given things, and is smaller (580bytes) even then $script.js, although, when requiring something, the filename of current script should be passed, like this `require('main.js', ['b.js'], function(){});` - But I don't want to rely on my realisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, since I've asked this question.
The solution to problem was just using requireJs, but defining modules in alternative way:

```
define(require){
  var dep1 = require("dep1"),
  dep2 = require("dep2");

  var MyModule = {//define something};

  return MyModule;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way how to implement your requirements with `require.js`:

```
// c.js
define(
    {/*something*/}
);

// b.js
define(['c.js'], function(c) {
    return Object.create(c);
});

// main.js
require(['b.js'], function(b) {
    var a = Object.create(b);
    a.foo = 'bar';
});
```

To me this seems pretty close to what you wanted to see, isn't it?

If you have multiple dependencies like jQuery, Backbone etc. and want to decouple everything you will end up with something like your second listing. However, a different approach could be to load the 'global' libraries (like jQuery) globally and without the loader and let `require.js` only handle your own classes and code parts.